# Changing Data Directory on MySQL 8

Tags: mysql-8.0

**Need:** To store / accesses dbTable data from a separate drive not the default

I was using MySQL 5.7 so far & as specified in the solution - [Link1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/111851) I added the my.ini file with the info as stated & it worked fine.

I now uninstalled MySQL 5.7, installed MySQL 8, created a my.ini file & specified the info as stated in this solution [Link2](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/226239). But when I check it still points to the default C:\ drive & hence unable to access data from the existing database stored in E:\ drive

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'datadir';
```

shows

```
C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data\
```

The new ***my.ini*** file which I have created as below in

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0 

[mysqld]
datadir = E:/MySqlData
secure-file-priv="E:/MySqlData/Uploads"
```

Hope the issue faced is clear, await inputs.

**Edit:**

I found this input - [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55519014/3127144) Could anyone let me know if this could be a reason ? Also any known hex editors for Windows 10 ?

**Update:** Even after removing the hex characters, the server still does not start if I point the parameter datadir in my.ini file to my database folder in another drive

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the directory where you want to write the data files is accessable for MySQL. I put it the security settings on Everyone.

You might need to copy the data also from old data directory to the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you specified `my.ini` location when you created the service, then you can open services, right click MySQL service, and choose properties. open `my.ini` file and check `datadir` location.

installed MySQL without specify `my.ini` location, navigate to mysql\bin directory using PowerShell or CMD. then execute the following command

```
.\mysqld --help --verbose > \output\location\out.txt
 notepad \output\location\out.txt
```

then search for `Default options are read from the following files in the given order:` this should specify my.ini location. and locate it from their.

and change `datadir` based inside the used `my.ini`

Comment: Thanks,what baffles me is that after specifying the file path in my.ini in C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini to point to E:\ drive & also updating the Windows Redistry, the server does not start. This behavior I notice in Ver 8, while it was working fine while using Ver 5.7. Anything else I need to check ?

Comment: would you please provide me with changes you did to registry? and the error you got when you try to start the SID using CL

Comment: The changes done to registry as per the solution provided (Step-3) in Link 2 cited in my query above. When I open Services.msc, right click on MySQL80 & click start services it takes a long time & at the end says cannot start. But if the 'datadir' points to the default drive, then the server starts immediately.

Comment: stop your SID service then open powershell, then execute the following command as administrator copy-item C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data\ E:\Data. after that open ini file and edit datadir to e:\Data then try to start the service.

Answer (score 0):

Try to save as your my.ini to ANSI. MySQL's default encoding of my.ini now is UTF-8. It should be ANSI, then restart the mysql server.

Answer (score 0):

It may be tricky if some detail was ignored. The `initialize` step is really crucial when the `Server` has been initialized before. There are 4 steps.

**1.Check the `MySql80` service configuration.**

Almost the time we will have a config, like this

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe" --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini" MySQL80
```

**2.Change the `datadir` property in the `my.ini` file.**

Maybe something like this `datadir=E:\mysql\Data`

**3.Remove all files in the `$datadir`.**

This is important and cannot be omitted. Or the `initialize` step will fail.

**4.Reinitialize the `MySQL80` service with **the actual same options**.**

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe" --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini" --initialize --console
```

As you see, just remove the service name and append two options to the service starting command.

After initialization, the password for root will be printed on the console. Check [this official document](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-directory-initialization.html#data-directory-initialization-password-assignment) for more information;

Comment: I am having a related issue.  I have turned the MySQL80 service off in the services program. I went and copied the database files located in C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/ to D:/MySQL, and then gone and restarted the server in services, but when I do that it tells me it started and then stopped immediately. I'm not sure what the issue is, I've quadruple checked all the paths - they are correct. And if I restore the path back to the C: location, the server starts fine.  Are you saying I need to delete/move the files in the C: location?